# How do factotums interact with truespeak?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I see that a truespeaker's caster level = their ranks in truespeak -3, does this mean that if a factotum found a lexicon he could learn those utterence based on the classes progression?

Answer (score 4):

A *truenamer’s* caster level is equal to his ranks in Truenaming − 3. No one else’s caster level is calculated that way, and that includes the factotum. Unless the factotum is also a truenamer, the ranks in Truenaming don’t contribute to any caster level, and certainly don’t result in any ability to use utterances.

If the factotum *is* also a truenamer, through multiclassing, then his truenamer caster level is calculated the same as it is for any other truenamer: based on Truenaming ranks. The only thing that is slightly unusual is that factotum treats Truenaming as a class skill, making it easier to keep the skill maxed. This character’s ability to use utterances is still solely defined by his truenamer levels, just with more ranks in Truenaming than he’d otherwise have at his truenamer level.

Comment: Ah ok, dissapointing but reasonable.

Comment: @Levi Note that the truenamer is a broken class: it literally does not function as written. There are numerous homebrew replacements for it, but as-is it’s extremely difficult to get it to do *anything at all* (and even then it’s rather mediocre). Wizards of the Coast does not appear to have even once playtested the class (or else they probably would have noticed that they left out the DC calculation formula for an entire class of utterances), and the chapter’s editing is extremely shoddy.

Comment: Hmmm, I have seen a rather legit seeming homebrew fix. Mostly just DC shifting and moving weaker powers down to lower utterence levels. if a factotum were invested enough to take enough ranks in true speak to be effective at it, I might make it a possible quest to discover a lexicon or to butter up a truespeaker. they'd have to discuss the interest with me first, but hey. DM powers op.